# Want to query the only row from Sqlite which was previously added

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

When a new data row is inserted in my sqlite database, I want to query the same row (not whole database) so that I can reflect this in my complex list view.
Currently I am using content observer to observe any change in my database but I don't know how I can query the only row which was previously inserted. Also onChange method of ContentObserver does not provide any information other than change in database.

How can we do this? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert a row into your sqlite database, you normally use `db.insert()`, and the return value from that function is the ID of the newly inserted row (if you have a _id column as `primary key` and `auto_increment`).

You can (and should) use that for your need.

Comment: Thank you Jan. But I want to know whether is there any way to retrieve this URI in onChange of observer (instead of normal java)? Means is there any callback method available which will provide me this URI?

Comment: This is the most appropriate way.